# Design: best way to store messages to users?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm writing an app that stores messages sent to users in a mysql database. These messages can have keywords that will be replaced by users data. at this time the dilemma that exists is what is the best way to store messages.

I have two options:

- Store the original message (including keywords) in a table, and recipients in another. when i need to get the message, can be processed before it is displayed. the biggest problem is that the message will be different each time the user changes his own data.
- Store the original message (including keywords) in a table and another table to store the recipients and the message the user is received. the disadvantage is the possible duplication of data, which can be a headache if the same message is sent to 20,000 users.

Comment: its like a messageing? You want to store unique message for any recipient ?

Comment: my idea is one table for users, 1:N to table2 messages and N:1 to receipients. you can control it seperate via relation table. Its very similar as your first option. Second option is bad idea i think.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest several tables.

- `message` - table, which will store message text
- `user` - table to store user account information
- `mail` - table to store `message_id`, `user_id_from`, `user_id_to`, `is_read` and other attributes to be associated with the specific conversation.

In a `message` table you should store message templates. When the message is fetched for display, it should be rendered. If you will need caching, you will be able to add rendered version of a message to the `mail` table (if rendering will consume too much of the resources).